# Нижняя кнопка слайдера имеет сдвиг вправо

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При сдвиге слайдера на сайте его кнопка остаётся на месте. Прошу помочь.
Слайдер вертикальный код и фото прилагается.Использую бутстрап 3.
Вот оригинал слайдера https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/GaMGR
https://jsfiddle.net/andrey15054/dnb4sen2/

```js
$('.carousel .vertical .item').each(function() {
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  for (var i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
    next = next.next();
    if (!next.length) {
      next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }

    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
```

```css
.carousel-inner.vertical {
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -30%;
  margin-top: -20%;
}

.carousel-inner.vertical>.item {
  -webkit-transition: .6s ease-in-out top;
  -o-transition: .6s ease-in-out top;
  transition: .6s ease-in-out top;
}

@media all and (transform-3d),
(-webkit-transform-3d) {
  .carousel-inner.vertical>.item {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform .6s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-perspective: 8000;
    perspective: 8000;
  }
  .carousel-inner.vertical>.item.next,
  .carousel-inner.vertical>.item.active.right {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 33.33%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 33.33%, 0);
    top: 0;
  }
  .carousel-inner.vertical>.item.prev,
  .carousel-inner.vertical>.item.active.left {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -33.33%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -33.33%, 0);
    top: 0;
  }
  .carousel-inner.vertical>.item.next.left,
  .carousel-inner.vertical>.item.prev.right,
  .carousel-inner.vertical>.item.active {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    top: 0;
  }
  .carousel-inner.vertical>.active {
    top: 0;
  }
  .carousel-inner.vertical>.next,
  .carousel-inner.vertical>.prev {
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
  }
  .carousel-inner.vertical>.next {
    left: 0;
    top: 33.33%;
    right: 0;
  }
  .carousel-inner.vertical>.prev {
    left: 0;
    top: -33.33%;
    right: 0;
  }
  .carousel-inner.vertical>.next.left,
  .carousel-inner.vertical>.prev.right {
    top: 0;
  }
  .carousel-inner.vertical>.active.left {
    left: 0;
    top: -33.33%;
    right: 0;
  }
  .carousel-inner.vertical>.active.right {
    left: 0;
    top: 33.33%;
    right: 0;
  }
  #carousel-pager .carousel-control.left {
    bottom: initial;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -30%;
  }
  #carousel-pager .carousel-control.right {
    top: initial;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -130%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div align="left" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
      <div id="carousel-pager" class="carousel slide " data-ride="carousel" data-interval="8000">
        <!-- Carousel items -->
        <div class="carousel-inner vertical">
          <div class="active item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/600/f44336/000000&text=First+Slide" class="img-responsive" data-target="#carousel-main" data-slide-to="0">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/600/e91e63/000000&text=Second+Slide" class="img-responsive" data-target="#carousel-main" data-slide-to="1">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/600/9c27b0/000000&text=Third+Slide" class="img-responsive" data-target="#carousel-main" data-slide-to="2">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/600/9c27b0/000000&text=Fourth+Slide" class="img-responsive" data-target="#carousel-main" data-slide-to="4">
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-pager" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-pager" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вижу только фото

Comment: Ссылки можно размещать с 10 очков репутации а у меня только три

Comment: Можно сразу вставлять код как на jsFiddle

Comment: Сделал смотри..

Comment: Имелась в виду кнопка "Пример кода на Javascript/HTML/CSS" чтобы можно было нажать на кнопку "Выполнить код". А так вы просто какой-то кусок html только с двумя кнопками и кусок css вставили

Comment: полный код сокращает stack

Comment: отредактировал так как это должно быть. Однако кнопок не видно. Подправьте теперь сами так чтоб соответствовало тому что у вас есть

Comment: добавил js. А как сделали оформление кода отдельно?

Comment: кнопка "Пример кода на Javascript/HTML/CSS" - прежде чем писать, понаводите на все кнопки в редакторе и посмотрите что они делают

Comment: Сейчас при редактировании, в самом низу вы можете увидеть "редактировать пример кода" - вот её нажимайте, редактируйте там чтоб получилось то что у вас и затем нажимайте "Вставить в сообщение" и сохраняйте